# The remaining parts of an ancient city

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-difference

What do you call the **remaining parts** of an ancient city like what you see within the picture that sometimes archeologists discover and unearth?

> 1- [Remnants](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/remnant) of a city 
>   2- [Remainings](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/remaining) of a city

To me they both work, but I am sure there is a fixed term to it. Also, I wonder if there is a better choice.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cities do not have remnants. Remaining parts of something does exist in general but is not an archaeological term per se.

Remnants is a word applied to objects. Not a site.

The proper term is **remains**:
"Sites may range from those with few or no remains visible above ground, to buildings and other structures still in use." [Wikipedia]

The remains of a city or archaeological remains of a city.

[remains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archaeological_site)

Answer (score 2):

"Remains" certainly may be used, but it's common to refer to these as "ruins".

> High on top of a hill overlooking Athens stands the proud remnants of four of the most well-known **ruins** preserved from the ancient world. The iconic Parthenon, Propylaia, Erechtheion and the temple of Athena Nike make up the Acropolis of ancient Athens.
>
> [The ancient city of Delphi] was also the location where the oracle of Delphi was filled with the spirit of Apollo and asked for guidance. Today, numerous **ruins** from the city remain
>
> Under the Romans, [Corinth] continued to prosper, which explains why the most interesting **ruins** to view here are of Roman build.

https://theculturetrip.com/europe/greece/articles/10-must-see-ancient-sites-in-greece/

> Today Caesarea is a popular ancient archaeological site boasting extensive and well-preserved **ruins**. Its most impressive structure is the large and picturesque ancient theatre, which overlooks the deep blue ocean.

https://www.triphistoric.com/explore/articles/incredible-roman-ruins-in-israel

> Perched atop an isolated rock plateau on the eastern edge of the Judaean Desert, overlooking the Dead Sea, the ancient fortress of Masada is one of the world’s most beautiful **ruins**.

[The Haunting Beauty of Masada, Israel's Famed Ruins](https://www.cntraveler.com/stories/2015-05-13/the-haunting-beauty-of-masada-israel-ruins)

and many more.

Formally, instead of "ruins", these may be referred to as "sites of archaeological interest", or something similar.

Comment: I think that ruins is when you do not have to excavate. "remains" require excavation.

Comment: @Lambie [**Excavating** Newly Discovered Ruins at America’s Biggest Shaker Settlement](https://www.archaeologicalconservancy.org/excavating-newly-discovered-ruins-at-americas-biggest-shaker-settlement/).   I think both are used and often synonymous